# How to retrieve URLs from a CSV file WordPress

Tags: wordpress, csv, woocommerce, jet-engine

I'm working on WordPress with WooCommerce Elementor and jet Engine.
I'm having trouble importing external URLs linked to products.

In JetEngine, I have a meta box that normally retrieves the URLs from the CSV file, but I can't get the product URLs with the CSV file import.

Do you know a way to get the URLs in the External URL text field?

Here's the CSV file with the URL :
[image]

Here's the CSV file import:
[image]

Here's the result:
[image]